# Regular expression to match but exclude from the selection

Tags: regex

I am trying to get the tokens in the message text so that they can be string replaced by the actual values. My text is

```
Hello &worls nice &to & Here &ok.
```

The expression (&\w+?)\W gives me

```
worls<whitespace>
to<whitespace>
ok.
```

However I need to exclude the last letter i.e whitespace or period

Testing link http://regexr.com?33nrg

Answer (score 2):

Test for word boundary (`\b`) instead of looking for non-word character `\W`.

Also it would be fine to learn how to work with regexp *match groups* in your tool or language of choice, so you can retrieve and use a substring matching any subexpression.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
&\S+[^\.\s]
```

Or, as Anton suggested.

```
&\S+\b
```